# Oracle SQL Developer Output Number Formatting (To_Char Problem)

Tags: sql, number-formatting

| Amount |
| --- |
| 1000000 |

My table is above. When I realise the query, I would like to see number format output like '1.000.000'.  No decimals.

```
select Amount = TO_CHAR(Number, '.') from Table
```

It is easy question but what is wrong with my code? (SQL Oracle Developer). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(amount, '999G999G999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS="."')
```

...etc...